# exporting vertical lines in org mode table to LaTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm using emacs as my editor and I am toying with org-mode which looks rather useful.

I'm generating a table (spreadsheet) in org mode and it is exported correctly to LaTeX apart from the vertical lines. Is there a way to export them? I want to have a way to define some of the vertical lines as visible.

Answer (score 27):

You can give the format to the table for LaTeX with `#+attr_latex:`, say:

```
#+attr_latex: :align |c|c|c|
|------+-----+-----|
|    A |   B |   C |
|------+-----+-----|
| 2.34 | 2.7 | 8.9 |
| 3.67 | 4.5 | 8.9 |
|------+-----+-----|
```

In older versions this used to be:

```
#+attr_latex: align=|c|c|c|
```

but this no longer works.

Comment: What about the horizontal lines in the table? Can they be made visible as well in the latex export?

Answer (score 6):

You should use [Column Groups](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-groups.html#Column-groups)

> can use a special row where the first field contains only ‘/’. The
>   further fields can either contain ‘<’ to indicate that this column
>   should start a group, ‘>’ to indicate the end of a column, or ‘<>’ to
>   make a column a group of its own. Boundaries between column groups
>   will upon export be marked with vertical lines.

This has the advantage of working in HTML export as well as LaTeX export.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, This doesn't seem to include lines on the far sides of the table, just the inner columns?

Comment: That does seem true

Answer (score 1):

Vertical lines in latex are defined by the `|` character in table definition. So, just separate the `l`'s and `r`'s with `|`'s in the `\tabular` definition before running latex, for example like this in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\\begin{tabular}{)(.*)}/$1 . join("|", split m{}, $2) . "}"/ge' < table.tex
```

**Update:** Oh I see. According to the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-groups.html), you should be able to indicate column groups by

```
| / | < |   |   | > | <> | < | > |
```

But, when I try it in my version of emacs and org-mode, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand your answer at all. It might be a problem with me. I have edited my question.

Comment: the reference is dead.... this is better https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-Groups.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `#+attr_latex` attribute to the table environment.  Here you can specify various features like the alignment and width.  See http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html for the manual information.