# Orgmode Beamer Presentation -- setting org table properties (esp. cell borders)

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm writing up a presentation in orgmode, for export to pdf via LaTeX. By default, orgmode tables don't have visible cell borders. I can find information for how to turn these on for export to HTML, but I don't see any documentation on how to set cell borders on when exporting to LaTeX (via C-c C-e {p|d}).

Comment: do you mean as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532762/exporting-vertical-lines-in-org-mode-table-to-latex ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exporting vertical lines in org mode table to LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532762/exporting-vertical-lines-in-org-mode-table-to-latex)