# No borders in table in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

This is how I wrote my table in org-mode:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|------+------+------|
| val1 | val2 | val3 |
| val4 | val5 | val6 |
```

This is the output I'm getting in `org-export-as-pdf` :

[image]

What I want is the borders for the table. The org-mode version I'm
using is 7.9.3f.

**UPDATE:**

With `#+ATTR_LaTeX: align=|c|c|c|`, I get the follwing table:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Solved that using putting horizontal lines on top and below of the table using `C-u C-c -` and `C-c -` respectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exporting vertical lines in org mode table to LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532762/exporting-vertical-lines-in-org-mode-table-to-latex)

Comment: may like http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html#Tables-in-HTML-export

Comment: @Chris I think vertical lines and border are different.

Comment: @Sibi, how are they different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want vertical lines, you need to specify it, hence something like:

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: align=|c|c|c|
```

in your old version of Org mode, or:

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :align |c|c|c|
```

in Org mode 8.